# IntelliJ 12 code coverage not working in editor for GWT Projects

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, code-coverage, emma

I'm trying IntelliJ 12, and I can't manage to get the line colored (red, green, yellow) in the editors after running the tests with coverage. 
Did anybody noticed the problem or it's just me not being able to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found out what was causing IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.0 (and also 12.0.1) to malfunction the code coverage.

My project is a GWT project, so there is some additional configuration to run the gwt client tests: the source directories are added in the classpath so that the gwt devmode can be ran headless to be tested:

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <!-- the following two lines, causes intellij coverage to stop working -->
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</additionalClasspathElement>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Adding the source folders to the classpath of surefire causes IntelliJ IDEA 12.x to misconfigure the project (the `.iml` file) and the coverage stops working.

Notice that this maven configuration doesn't have any impact in IntelliJ IDEA 11.x, that works perfectly.

To reproduce the bug, just add the `<additionalClasspathElement>` to your surefire configuration, then rightclick on your project and do a "Maven->Reimport", then run the tests with coverage; and you'll see that the editor misses all informations about the lines coverage.

I managed to reproduce the issue, and I am going to submit the bug report.

The workaround would be to comment out the two lines of `<additionalClasspathElement>` and do a "Maven->Reimport", then uncomment those if you need.

Bug reported [IDEA-97920](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97920), it'll be fixed in 12.0.2

Comment: This bug will be fixed in 12.0.2

Comment: This bug should be fixed in IDEA 12.0.2 (EAP will be published soon, release is coming in a couple of week or so).

Comment: This problem also affects normal dependencies on source code directories! I.e. when I add a directory above my sources directory as a compile dependency (Project Structure > Dependencies) the coverage results will not be displayed (neither in gutter nor full line). Also the "Coverage Summary" will show all classes twice.
This problem persists in IDEA 14.0.3!

Answer (score 8):

By default code coverage results are displayed only in the left gutter and may be hard to notice:

[image: coverage displayed in gutter]

You can either change the gutter colors or configure IntelliJ IDEA to change the **background** of the whole lines (instead of the foreground) depending on their coverage status:

[image: coverage background settings]

Now it's much easier to see the coverage status:

[image: coverage displayed as background]

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X and IntelliJ 12, no colored left gutter is visible, nor Colors & Fonts have any effect.

Comment: Please share a project to reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's pretty interesting. I just tried with a new project and the gutter shows up. It makes me think that effectively it is a problem with my project (maven project, with multi modules). I'll try to do more investigation to find out the reason. If I can reproduce it in a mini project, I'll share. Thanks.

Comment: We tried to reimport the project from maven into a fresh intellij, and it looks like the strange behavior I posted only happen with our project. I can't figure out what is so special in our project that causes the misbehavior, since with new projects we created to reproduce the issue, everything works just fine. It looks to me that there is some hidden bug somewhere, but I can't help to spot it, yet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Weird. If you'll manage to reproduce it, submit a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA.

Comment: It may be related to this bug (?): http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6817 
one comment mentions "If application with tests is in root of opened project, it shows coverage. When the same app is in some nested directory (ie /virtualenv/src/app/), coverage is not shown."

Comment: Update: I tried to create a mvn submodule in a mvn project and the coverage works; so for my case the problem is something different than the one spotted in the mentioned bug report.

Comment: I found the cause. I provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using IntelliJ 13 on a Mac with the Darcula theme.

I did not notice the green/red colours at first as they are very dull and don't stand out from the black background.

However if you look very carefully in the lefthand on the left of the line numbers (if you have them configured) you will see them faintly.

You can easily configure the colours to make them more noticeable.

The defaults ought to be changed by IntelliJ in a future release.