# IDEA: How to change toolbar color indicating whether particular line is covered by tests?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've embraced the [darker side of productive coding](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and now find the "line covered" and "line not covered" color not too flashy and not sufficiently distinctive. I'd like to make it brighter (bright green and bright red would be nice)

How can i change it please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the colors in settings, but not the opacity which is hardcoded:

[image: coverage color]

If it's not possible to achieve what you want by changing the color, [submit a request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) to make the opacity configurable.

Comment: Where about in settings can this be changed please?

Comment: See the screenshots in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13907716/104891).